# OpenLayers 3 measure example

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, measurements, html5

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dkcz/a6pp9vwz/7/) is my fiddle, which is exact copy of  [Openlayers 3 measure example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/measure.html).

What am I doing wrong when my fiddle isn't working? I can't see the blue dot to start measuring my path or area (same problem like in my localhost environment project)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/a6pp9vwz/9/ working for me.

Console log said "`$` not defined". `$` is a jQuery class, so you need a jQuery environment to enable AJAX requests. You can enable jQuery in JSFiddle in the "Frameworks & Extensions" tab.

Comment: Thanks. I will look if I have any problems with script versions imports in my localhost project...